# Fail starting Arduino IDE Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: arduino-ide

for unknown reason, my Arduino IDE 1.8.12 stopped starting up ( worked OK before ).

Can anyone share some steps understanding why ?

**edit1**
after executing `./arduino`

```
guy@desktop:~/arduino-1.8.12$ ./arduino
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
Set log4j store directory /home/guy/.arduino15
Gtk-Message: 17:15:18.630: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionsIndexer.parseIndex(ContributionsIndexer.java:134)
    at processing.app.BaseNoGui.initPackages(BaseNoGui.java:483)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:273)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:150)
guy@desktop:~/arduino-1.8.12$
```

Comment: it was a temporary problem with platform index file on server. to recover see https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=690045.0

Comment: did not solve the problem

Comment: then start `./arduino` from command line to see the log

Comment: see edit 1 in question

Comment: Delete your arduino storage directory: `rm -rf ~/.arduino15` being careful not to delete ~ instead.

Comment: it is the problem. did you delete the `package_index.json` file and the `cache` folder?

Comment: @Juraj I did delete the folder as noted on comment 1 ( in arduino15 older ), (in arduino folder ) there was nothing to delete

Comment: @Majenko I `mv` that folder, and now it is almost as fresh install ( what was important to me was all repositories that were installed ). it seems that additional boards should be configed again

Comment: and the file? did you delete package_index.json?

Comment: @Juraj - perhaps not, because I see it ( or it was re-created ). Lucky I was `mv` that folder. But again, I'll have to re-define boards. On the other hand, tools as: decoder, and 8266 Data upload, are there...

Comment: nothing should change if you only delete that one a file and the cache folder. stack trace decoder and SPIFFS upload tool are in Sketchbook folder in tools

Comment: @Juraj For some reason, I can't OTA now for that specific PC for every MCU I try - it is not a code problem. When I'm using my MAC laptop, same code, same MCU - it works as expected. Error ia " o response from device"

Comment: Firewall does this

Comment: @Juraj Mr.Know-all. Thankyou